# Nested directive and ng-repeat exception TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null

Tags: angularjs, controller, nested, directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am learning angularjs by developing map directives. The most outer directive is myMap, then myCircle, myMarker, etc.... are the child directives. At this time, I have only the myMap and myCirle directives.
The map and circles works fine if I dont use the ng-repeat. As soon as I use ng-repeat, the angularjs throws exceptions

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null at https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular.js:3012:13...**
as soon as I start draw the map. I spend many hours but still dont know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/LI7lh28OAhh59HeuL7O1?p=preview

```
 app.directive('myMap', function () {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          replace: true,
          transclude: true,
          template: "<div ng-transclude id='mapCanvas' ></div>",
          scope: {
              center: '=',
              zoom: '='
          },
          controller: function ($scope) {
            console.log('map directive: controller...')
            this.drawCircle = function (data) {

               var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                            map: $scope.map,
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(data.center.latitude, data.center.longitude),
                            radius: data.radius,
                            strokeColor: data.strokeColor,
                            strokeOpacity: data.strokeOpacity,
                            strokeWeight: data.strokeWeight,
                            fillColor: data.fillColor,
                            fillOpacity: data.fillOpacity
                        });

              return circle;

            };
          },
          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              var mapOptions = {
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(scope.center.latitude, scope.center.longitude),
                        zoom: scope.zoom
                    };
              // comment this line out will make the directives work without problem.
              scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), mapOptions);

              console.log("Map directive:Link: initialize the map ..." + JSON.stringify(scope.center));
          }
        }
    });

    app.directive('myCircle', function ($timeout) {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          replace: true,
          scope: {},
          require:'^myMap',
          link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
              console.log("circle directive:Link..." );

           var data = {
                        center:{latitude: attrs.lat, longitude:attrs.lng},
                        radius: parseFloat(attrs.radius),
                        strokeColor: attrs.strokeColor,
                        strokeOpacity: attrs.strokeOpacity,
                        strokeWeight: attrs.strokeWeight,
                        fillColor: attrs.fillColor,
                        fillOpacity: attrs.fillOpacity
                    };

            $timeout( function(){
              console.debug('callling the map.drawCircle...')
              ctrl.drawCircle(data)
            }, 1000);
          }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because when creating the map with this statement:

```
 scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), mapOptions);
```

The content in the `mapCanvas` element will be *removed and replaced* with the google map widget.

Then when the `ng-repeat` is trying to populate elements from `map.circles`, it can't find the original element that those populated elements should be appended to.

To solve this, you could change the template of the `myMap` directive to be something like this to prevent the original element from being replaced.

```
template: "<div><div id='mapCanvas'></div><div ng-transclude></div></div>",
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/A0yYyoB5LCfTM0ixVcMy?p=preview

PS. There are a lot of typos in attribute bindings of the `my-circle` directive.

Comment: That is it. thanks you very much. I could not figure it out because it works without ng-repeat. Thanks a lot.